# Printing character and append them in single line python

Tags: python

I have many strings in a file(inputfile.txt). Each string has 99 characters.
Now I have a file (position.txt) where I have some numbers.
I like to print those particular positions for each string.

inputfile:

```
BCCDDDCDCCDDDDDDABCDABCABDBACBDCAADDCBCABACBCCABCACBCCCCCBDBACABBBCBCBBCCACADAACCCBABADBCCAAABBCCBB
BCCDDDCDCDDDDCDDABCDABCABDBACBDCAADDCBCABACBCCABCACBCCCCCBDBADABBBCBCBACCACADAACCCBABADBCCAAABBCCBB
BCCDDDCDCDDDDCCDABCDABCABDBACBDCAADDABCABACBCCABCACBCCCCCBDBACABBBCBCBACCACADAACCCBABADBCCAAABBCCBB
```

I need output like this outputfile:

```
DDDCBCABACBCCABCABCBBCCACADAACCC
CDDDCDCDDDDCDDABCDABCABACBDCAADC
CCDDDCDCDDDDCCDABCDABCABDBACBCCA
```

the positions are random numbers.

Position file:

```
10
11
16
20
24
30
32
33
34
36
43
46
47
48
50
53
54
58
60
62
63
64
69
71
73
74
76
77
82
```

I'm using this code:

```
***seq=np.loadtxt('inputfile', dtype='str')
p = open( "osition.txt", "r" )
for line in p:
    l=int(line)
    ll=l-1
    print(seq[ll], end="")***
```

It prints input in one line like this:

```
DDDCBCABACBCCABCABCBBCCACADAACCCCDDDCDCDDDDCDDABCDABCABACBDCAADCCCDDDCDCDDDDCCDABCDABCABDBACBCCA
```

I'm very new to python. Please help me to get my desired output and save it in a text file.
Thank you

Comment: What exactly is your question? Do you want that same output, but with each letter on a different line? Or do you want that string to be sent to a text file?

Comment: I  like to print the characters (position of the characters I read from file position.txt) of a string in one line. But when I go to a new string, the characters should be printed in a new line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the above code snippet, the contents of 'inputfile' is being read as array of string.  Based on the comment that you need - "print those particular positions for each string", you will need to add another loop to iterate over each string and print the string.

Suggested code :

```
seq=np.loadtxt('inputfile', dtype='str')
p = open( "position.txt", "r" )
for file_String in seq :   # Iterate over each string
    for line in p:
        l=int(line)
        ll=l-1
        print(file_String[ll], end="")
    print ("")     # Adding new line after each string.
```

Optimized code to write to file :

```
import numpy as np
seq=np.loadtxt('inputfile.txt', dtype='str')
pos=np.loadtxt('position.txt', dtype='int')

with open( "output.txt", "w" ) as nf :
    for fileString in seq :   # Iterate over each string
        s = "".join (map(lambda x: fileString[x], p))  # Replace second for loop by map.
        nf.write(s + "\n")    # "\n" can be replaced by os.sep if using non-linux OS
```

Comment: Thank you, Prashant. It is helpful. but I like to append all my output in one file. It only prints one line. I like my output to be printed on each new line for each string like this: DDDCBCABACBCCABCABCBBCCACADAACCC
CDDDCDCDDDDCDDABCDABCABACBDCAADC
CCDDDCDCDDDDCCDABCDABCABDBACBCCA

Comment: Indrani,  The simple change would be to just add a new line after each string iteration.   I have updated the code above for the same.

Comment: @IndraniChoudhuri , I would appreciate if you could upvote the answer if it helped resolve your issue.

Comment: Thank you @Prashanth Mariswamy. Your answer is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

`end` is a keyword argument for the print() function, you can read about it [here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-purpose-of-end-in-Python)

Get rid of the `end = ""` in your print statement, that's the delimiter and you're setting it to `''` - empty string, which means after every print statement, you have an empty string printed, and hence when you start printing the next time in the loop, the print continues from the same position.
Note that by default, the delimiter is `\n` which means a newline character.

so
`print(seq[l1])` is what you want, as now `end = '\n'`

Comment: I used end=" " so that I can print all the position (from position.txt) in one line for a string. But I have many string. When I iterate over string then I need to print my input in new line. I'm not sure how to do that. Thank you